# Handle missing dynamic chunks after new deployment with Webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, angular-ui-router, webpack-4

I have an AngularJs (1.7) SPA with Webpack (4.x).

This is how we create chunknames:

```
  config.output = {
    path: PATHS.build,
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename:  `[name]${isDev ? '' : '.[contenthash:8]'}.bundle.js`,
    chunkFilename: `chunks/[name]${isDev ? '' : '.[contenthash:8]'}.chunk.js`
  };
```

The  lazyloading is done in the state definitions in ui-router basically like this:

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('reports', {
      url: '/projects/:project_id/reports',
      lazyLoad: function($transition$) {
        const injector = $transition$.injector().get('$injector');
        return import(/* webpackChunkName: "admin.reports.module" */ './reports')
          .then(mod => {
            injector.loadNewModules([mod.default]);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            throw new Error('An error occured, ' + err);
          });
      }
    })
```

After a deployment due changes to a module in a "dynamic" chunk - the filename will change of this chunk ([contenthash] has changed).

When a logged in user (where all bundled assets are loaded **before** the last deployment) now tries to open a route with the new chunk - the chunk is not there (404) and  it will fail with:

```
Transition Rejection($id: 4 type: 6, message: The transition errored, detail: Error: An error occured, Error: Loading chunk 14 failed.
(error: admin.reports.module.8fc31757.chunk.js))
```

Is there a common way to circumvent/deal with this?

Maybe more in general: How can changes to a bundled web app be detected? Is there a common way to trigger a reload? Is a manual refresh always neccessary?

Answer (score 6):

I think there are a few ways to circumvent this, since the javascript in the current context isn't aware of the new hash of the content generated by the latest build you could try:

1.) You could try setting up an http redirect on the hashed files: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections
The browser will request the old file and the server can point to the new file instead of returning 404. If all of your files follow a convention and only store one of the file at a time ex: `component.hash.js` then this should be pretty easy.

2.) A hacky client approach would be handling the transition-rejection in a try catch and reload the page, without the cache to get the new assets. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload

There's always more than one approach, but this is what I could think of to solve the issue.

Comment: I agree that there is more than one approach - but I am looking for a common approach that has already proven to work. Redirecting to the new file is complicated because there is a hash in the filename from the _content_ of the file. This could be done with the manifest from Webpack. Maybe someone has done this before?

Comment: A location reload has to any side effects and the app would still be broken for the user, when this is done in the routing example above. This could be the last straw - telling the user to reload when the import promise is rejected.